# Is jQuery resetting the border attribute with animate()?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-animate

Why isn't this working? The div has 5px border, on hover, the border should go up to 10 pixels and on mouse out it should go back to 5, but somehow, the border gets reset to 0 and then starts both animations.

Here's my code:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.4.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("div").hover(function(){
        $(this).filter(":not(:animated)").animate({ borderWidth: 10 });
    },
    function(){
        $(this).filter(":not(:animated)").animate({ borderWidth: 5 });
    });
});
</script>
<style>
div{
border:5px solid #ccc;
}
</style>

<div>
Test div
</div>
```

I've tried without the border shorthand (border-width and border-style) and it actually doesn't change anything.

Comment: What I'm seeing [here](http://jsfiddle.net/kENeY/) is that when the animation starts, it sets the border to 0px first.  Is that what you mean?

Comment: Yeah, I just saw that. Is this a jQuery feature?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is that `borderWidth` is a shorthand property for `borderLeftWidth`, `borderRightWidth`, `borderTopWidth`, `borderBottomWidth`.

The animate method is not working with shorthand properties. You need to use each and all of them.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("div").hover(function(){
        $(this).filter(":not(:animated)").animate({
            borderLeftWidth: 10,
            borderRightWidth: 10,
            borderTopWidth: 10,
            borderBottomWidth: 10
        });
    },
    function(){
        $(this).filter(":not(:animated)").animate({
            borderLeftWidth: 5,
            borderRightWidth: 5,
            borderTopWidth: 5,
            borderBottomWidth: 5
        });
    });
});
```

**Demo**: http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/ytKeK/

See the official reply to a bug report at http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/7085